# Gravar usuário no realtime database do firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-database, realtime-database

Boa tarde!

Estou enfrentando um problema para gravar meu usuário em meu realtime database do firebase. O cenário é o seguinte :

Tenho meu código de criação de usuário utilizando o método createUserWithEmailAndPassword, segundo a documentação do firebase, após esse método ser executado ele retorna um objeto que no caso é o usuário. O problema está quando eu tento acessar o uid desse usuário criado para gravá-lo no realtime database, pois quando eu tento acessar esse uid é retornado um erro dizendo que o uid é indefinido, porém se eu der um console.log(usuário) eu consigo visualizar esse uid. O que posso fazer para resolver esse problema ?

Segue o codigo:

```
   const firebase = require('firebase');


// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebase_config = {

};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebase_config);

let user = {
    uid: '',
    displayName: 'teste',
    email: 'email@email.com',
    password: '11111111',
    roles: ['admin','user'],
}

firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,user.password)
    .then((newUser) =>{
        console.log(newUser)
        user.uid = newUser.uid

    firebase
        .database().ref('users/'+user.uid)
        .update(user)
        .then(()=>{
        console.log('usuario ' +user.displayName + ' criado')
    })
}).catch(console.log)
```

Esse é o erro gerado :
Error: Reference.update failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'users.undefined.uid'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Troque o trecho de código:

```
user.uid = newUser.uid
```

Por:

```
useruid = newUser.key
```